# Automatically Move Chart Y data

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on a project and want to include some VBA code to move the data series in a chart automatically once a button is pressed.  It would also need to be replicable so the chart only includes only the previous 6 months.

WHen a button is pressed new data is automatically entered.

```
Sub MoveChart2()
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 3").Activate
    ActiveChart.PlotArea.Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range( _
    "'Product Breakdown'!$D$2:$D$7,'Product Breakdown'!$AC$2:$AN$7").Resize(0,2)
End Sub
```

I can't seem to figure out how to change the $AC$2:$AN$7 range based on the date of the column.

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70792289/edit) to include sample data and what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: How should the ranges for the chart change when the button is pressed?

Comment: Just use today() to calculate the 6 month window and pick the data that way. Did that for 3, 6, 9 and 12 months in service with series lines for each as well as forecasts…

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand the situation you're describing (an image would definitely come handy). You entered a string that includes this substring `$AC$2:$AN$7`. Why not make reference to a cell?

Kind of like this :

```
"'Product Breakdown'!" & Range("A1").Value ,"'Product Breakdown'!" & Range("A2").Value
```

I hope this helps! ( If it does please set this answer as the proper solution :) )